# Windows: Force specific network adapter

Tags: networking, windows-8, google-chrome, proxy

**Specs:**

Windows 8 server (x64) with two connections/adapters, 1 is wired and 1 is a tethered connection through my phone.

**Question:**

How can I force my browser(chrome) to connect over the wired connection only?

**I've tried:**

Looking at previous answers (all unsatisfactory), a program called ForceBindIp (didn't work for my platform) and googeling for a proxy that could route traffic through a specified interface (anybody know a proxy that can do this?)

Comment: "ForceBindIP appears to work on 64bit Windows 7 if you put the DLL into the SYSWOW64 folder instead of the System32 folder."  Did you try that?

Comment: The executable was already located in the syswow folder I can try to put it in the system32 folder.

Comment: OK the EXE was in there, but was the DLL as well?

Comment: yes, both bindip.dll and ForceBindIp.exe are in the syswow64 folder

Comment: You're running Windows Server 2012, right? How did you try using ForceBindIP, exactly? Keep in mind that latest version was released in 2009, and it doesn't officially support anything past Windows XP/Server 2003. It's basically a hack, and it might break or not work at all. The official page reads: "Please note however that certain programs may still end up using the default interface if they implement connections that do not use the standard winsock functions." It won't work with 64-bit programs, but there is no 64-bit Chrome for Windows so that's not the issue.

Comment: @and31415 is there a solution for windows 8 (64)?

Answer (score 1):

for that you need a third party software, and configure rules for incoming / outgoing connections for every network connection BlindIP seems to be tour best shot, because windows doesn't allow such configurations